# Generating links from words using an input filter

Tags: 6, navigation

Does anyone know of a D6 module that can do this easily? Really I just want to find certain words in forum posts and link them to other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with [Glossary](http://drupal.org/project/glossary).